# iphone - How to add a heat map to a google map

Tags: objective-c, heatmap

Im looking for an SDK that provides the tools to draw a heat map over a google map given a set of points with values.

I've seen Locomatix, but we prefer a site that doesnt require an API key to use the service.

Do you know any?

Comment: or if you could just point out a tutorial? If I draw an image with the set of points I would have to put it on top of the map, will zoom on the map still be enabled?